# Why does this Redshift create table query with DISTKEY and DISTSTYLE not work?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I run this query in Redshift:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    auto_increment              BIGINT          IDENTITY(0, 1),
    id                          INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    col_1                       INTEGER         NOT NULL DISTKEY SORTKEY,
    foreign key(col_1) references foreign_table(id),
    col_2                       INTEGER,
    col_3                       VARCHAR(255),
    col_4                       TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    col_5                       TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DISTSTYLE ALL;
```

But I get an error saying:
`Cannot specify DISTKEY for column "col_1" of table "my_table" when DISTSTYLE is NONE or EVEN;`

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Distribution Style can be one of several options. From [Distribution Styles - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html):

- **Auto:** Amazon Redshift assigns an optimal distribution style based on the size of the table data.
- **Event:** The leader node distributes the rows across the slices in a round-robin fashion.
- **Key:** The rows are distributed according to the values in one column.
- **All:** A copy of the entire table is distributed to every node.

This specification:

```
col_1                       INTEGER         NOT NULL DISTKEY SORTKEY,
```

is telling Redshift to use the **Key** distribution style, since it is nominating the column to use as the `DISTKEY`.

However, the `DISTSTYLE ALL` at the bottom is telling Redshift to use the `All` distribution style.

Thus, Redshift is giving an error because two *different* distribution styles have been requested. You will need to pick one, not both.

Given that you have selected a column as `DISTKEY`, you should probably remove `DISTSTYLE ALL`.

A quick guide for `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY` is:

- For `DISTKEY`, use the column that is most frequently used in JOINs
- For`SORTKEY`, use the column that is most frequently used in WHEREs

I notice that you have selected one column for both `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY`. You might want to confirm that this is suitable for your data.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify a column as `DISTKEY` when your `DISTSTYLE` is `ALL` .

What `DISTSTYLE ALL` means is that your table will be copied as a whole and stored across all the nodes, so you're not distributing the data by any `KEY`.

So if you want to distribute the data based on a `DISTKEY`, you'll have to set `DISTSTYLE KEY`.